# Should the site be refocussed to an SEO site?

Tags: discussion, seo

http://www.google.com.au/search?q=site%3Awebmasters.stackexchange.com+seo&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-GB:official&client=firefox-a

Approximately 203 pages are somehow related to SEO. Let's be conservative and say that half of them are duplicate links to the same questions. Out of 339 questions that's a whopping 30% of questions on **one very specific and specialised category**.

My metrics may be flawed - Searching for "SEO" in the search only tags 60 questions, but a lot of the questions are not tagged SEO. Even 60/339 is 17% which is still a reasonably percentage.

Should the site be re-focussed as an all-things SEO repository?

Comment: +1: cause in some way true.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

SEO is a "big deal" for some people. I think if you go to webmasterworld.com you'll find the same kinds of emphasis on SEO as here. Why "refocussed on SEO" though? Similar to stackoverflow.com, that has a lot of questions about C# although I don't know C# from a hole in the ground I can still use stackoverflow to ask about things I am interested in. Nobody is saying "let's refocus stackoverflow to a C# site".

Comment: +1 , a very good comparison. When Stack Overflow was initially 'seeded', it was very, very focused on C# because that's what the founding community dealt with on a day to day basis.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't give you -1 because I have still too few points, but the comparison macth in some way, but it's wrong in another way. Stackoverflow is not about C# and I'm glad about it, but on stackoverflow the C# questions are NOT marked all as community wiki, as it happens here for almost any SEO question.

Answer (score 2):

I think it will probably level out slightly over time. I feel like most of the current SEO questions are covering the basics, and perhaps in future many of the new questions will need to be closed as duplicates.

SEO is a large topic. Often when you make a change to a web page, you need to consider the SEO aspect of it (either directly or via UX). But at the same time it's just one of the many concerns of webmasters.

Incidentally, there is an [SEO proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1/white-hat-seo) in the committal phase of Area 51 so if that gains traction then there *will* be a pure SEO Q&A site. Pro Webmasters does not need to change its focus.

Comment: The SEO proposal actually came before "Pro Webmasters", and at one point it was far ahead of "Pro Webmasters" in terms of supporters,  but it floundered. I don't think it's going to make it through commitment as long as this site is already answering SEO questions.

Comment: @Kinopiko: I agree - in fact I posted a comment on that proposal that it would be covered by our beloved Pro Webmasters. However, I think that most of the proposals currently in the commitment phase will eventually make it to private beta. Whether they reach 'critical mass' is another matter.