# Should SEO be spun off to a new SE site?

Tags: discussion

I can't answer for other 'regulars', but I find that most of the SEO questions are from newbies and are a distraction from what I find interesting and want to learn about and help with.

This has been an issue for some time [Should the site be refocussed to an SEO site?](https://webmasters.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148/should-the-site-be-refocussed-to-an-seo-site)

Has there been any thought given to a stack exchange SEO specific site?  There seems to be enough interest in the topic to support it and it would eliminate much of the noise in webmasters.

Comment: Without SEO questions this site would be barren.

Comment: @JohnConde right now, out of the top 10 questions only 4 of them are SEO related.  I suppose that stat also negates my question :P but there are times when the SEO stuff and the inanity and desperation of the questions drives me nuts.

Comment: I agree with John, the focus of this site is pretty narrow already.   Putting SEO into your ignored tags could hide those questions from you if you are less interested in those.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller - oh, never knew I could do that.  Thanks

Comment: For an SEO site to be started up, there'd need to be enough interested people setting up a proposal at [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com). If that happened and got off the ground, then it might mean that SEO is declared off-topic here. But.. OTOH, it would be unlikely to get off the ground if it was declared too similar to our current focus here.

Comment: My thought would be that SEO is very much a webmastering topic, and that of all the places to discuss SEO a webmasters Q&A site would be the most appropriate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think SEO is important to our site and webmastering in general, and brings us a lot of traffic (ironically or not). Splitting it off would do little to build a community anew and would leave us with a lot less of a community here.

I like a well-formed SEO question as much as any other, but getting the right questions is key. I'm pretty bored with "is this bad for SEO" questions that affect the sense of inanity and desperation you feel; most of the time there isn't even any reason why a user thinks is *would* affect it. There's also still a lot of talk about focusing on keywords, when we should have moved past that already.

What we probably need is a bit stricter moderation of less thought-through questions. If a user just asks "is this bad?" or "how do I target?" without including any real substance, perhaps we shouldn't be as reticent to downvote or raise a flag....

Comment: People are asking poor questions because the industry changes quickly and there is a lot of out of date information available.    Unless the question has already been answered, I don't see a good basis for closing the question.   This site is one of the best we to get up to date SEO information onto the internet where it can be found.

Answer (score 1):

No. SEO is not a magic trick to show off. There is no possible SEO of quality without a full understanding of being a webmaster.

Comment: I completley agree with you.